# MySql Join According to a Column

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to select rows both from **Report** and **Terminal** table to create such a row like this:

```
+----+-------------------+---------------------+---------+-------+--------+-----+---------+------+
| id | mac_adresi        | zaman               | fabrika | kumes | makina | kat | sol_sag | adet |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+---------+-------+--------+-----+---------+------+
|  3 | 97-F9-2C-55-19-72 | 2017-11-18 22:43:29 | Çorum2  | Ana2  | 22     | 12  | So2     | 213  |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+---------+-------+--------+-----+---------+------+
```

**Report** table;

```
+----+-------------------+------+---------------------+
| id | mac_adresi        | adet | zaman               |
+----+-------------------+------+---------------------+
|  3 | 97-F9-2C-55-19-72 | 213  | 2017-11-18 22:43:29 |
+----+-------------------+------+---------------------+
```

**Terminal** table;

```
+----+-------------------+---------+-------+--------+-----+---------+
| id | mac_adresi        | fabrika | kumes | makina | kat | sol_sag |
+----+-------------------+---------+-------+--------+-----+---------+
| 86 | 97-F9-2C-55-19-72 | Çorum2  | Ana2  | 22     | 12  | So2     |
+----+-------------------+---------+-------+--------+-----+---------+
```

In **Terminal** table, `mac_adresi` is a *Primary Key*,

In **Report** table, `mac_adresi` is a *Foreign Key*.

I have tried this query but result is not what I want to achieve.

```
SELECT report.*,terminal.fabrika,terminal.kumes,terminal.makina,terminal.kat,terminal.sol_sag FROM report JOIN terminal ORDER BY id DESC limit 10
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Missing `ON()` clause ?

Comment: `SELECT report.*,terminal.fabrika,terminal.kumes,terminal.makina,terminal.kat,terminal.sol_sag FROM report JOIN terminal ON report.mac_adresi
 = terminal.mac_adresi ORDER BY id DESC limit 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should set the ON clause for join

```
SELECT 
      report.*
      ,terminal.fabrika
      ,terminal.kumes
      ,terminal.makina
      ,terminal.kat
      ,terminal.sol_sag 
FROM report JOIN terminal on  report.mac_adresi = Terminal.mac_adresi   
ORDER BY id DESC limit 10
```